# Is there a way to turn an app into a floating one?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, kindle-for-android

I want to search a specific installed dictionary app which is on my device while I'm reading a book in the Kindle app.  Is there a way to turn an app into a floating app?  Anything even close to this idea even exists?

Note: I'm aware of pre-made floating dictionaries but I'm looking to use the one I have.

OS: 4.1
S3

Answer (score 0):

Kindle has a built-in dictionary that you can download. When you highlight a word, it shows the meaning to you. Is that not good enough?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I know on the PC version I can download a dictionary but I don't see a setting in my Android one.  And, I need a French one.

Comment: @verve I'm not sure if there's a setting. Just long-press on a word, and something should pop-up. I don't have a book that's French, so I can't test. But the dictionary is English; not sure if it has French. See if it works.