# Floating browser window that can be minimized?

Tags: browser

My problem: I need to have an open web page floating on top of my Kindle app which can be minimized to the screen and not on the status bar as that covers the book.  What I need is an open resizeable window with transparency settings so I can read and research at the same time.  How do I go about solving this?

Comment: This is also a duplicate of your other question,[Is there a way to turn an app into a floating one?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63483)

Comment: @onik: I'm not that stupid.  I'm asking two different things.  This question has to do with one thing: browsers and the existence of a solution for my problem.  My question pertains to whether you can make your own floating app out of any app.

Comment: I meant "my other question pertains to..."

Comment: Browsers are Apps. The only difference I see between the two questions is that this one asks "how to make a browser window float" while the other asks "how to make an app window float". I don't think that, if a solution exists, that there will be one specific to browsers, therefore I also consider this a duplicate question.

Comment: @Flow I think they can be considered as different questions. If no generic solution exists (e.g. making an app float), then it may be good enough for verve if a specific solution exists (e.g. making a browser float).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boat Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatbrowser.free&hl=en) has a floating tab feature that can minimize to the notification bar (pulldown menu). You can also resize this window. It's the closest I can recommend.

[image: Boat Browser]
<sup>*Boat Browser* (click for larger image)</sup>